# jQuery outerHeight() returns undefined instead of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since jQuery 3 `.outerHeight()` returns `undefined` instead of `null` if called on a non-existing element. This causes problems when adding up heights of elements that don't exist, because `number` + `undefined` now results in `NaN`. While prior to jQuery 3 `number` + `null` would return `number`.

```
var lorem = $('#div1').outerHeight() + $('#div2').outerHeight();
```

Returns `NaN` if for example `#div2` does not exist.

Potential solution:

```
undef2null = function(myvar) {
    if (myvar === undefined) {return null;}
    else {return myvar;}
}
```

Would turn above code into:

```
var lorem = undef2null($('#div1').outerHeight()) + undef2null($('#div2').outerHeight());
```

Is there a more elegant solution than this?

Comment: JavaScript does not have integers.

Comment: @AluanHaddad LoL. What? Okay, consider it as `number`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, i guess Aluan wanted to say: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures, but it is not so important in this case... :) Oh, right terminology police...always awake. :)

Comment: @sinisake Me or Aluan is RTP? `:D` Dude, it's midnight. I am gonna hit the bed. You are wrong.

Comment: We're writing programs it's important that we be precise. Regardless what would 1 plus null mean?

Comment: @AluanHaddad `1 + null` gives `1` and `1 + undefined` gives `NaN`.

Comment: I've changed the reference to 'integer' into 'number'.

Comment: Hint: `1 + (undefined || 0) === 1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can guard against an undefined *or* null value using the `||` operator:

```
($('#div1').outerHeight() || 0)
```

...which is less typing than calling a function on each of the potentially problem values (although obviously you could make a one-line function out of that if you wanted to).

Or instead of a function that checks a single value to see if it is `undefined` you could write a function that adds up all supplied arguments, checking each:

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    result += arguments[i] || 0;
  return result;
}

console.log( addNumbers(1,2,3) );
console.log( addNumbers(1,undefined,3) );
console.log( addNumbers(1,undefined,null) );
```

(Note that the code I've shown doesn't actually test the type of the supplied values, so if you called it with strings or whatever it would happily concatenate those into the result. You could add an extra test for non-numeric/undefined/null values if desired.)

Answer (score 4):

It seems strange to write a method to turn `undefined` to `null` when you really want to treat both as zero.

To coerce both `undefined` and `null` to zero, you can

```
someValThatMightBeNullOrUndefined || 0
```

Comment: Note that this also tests for `NaN` and is therefore reliable.